# Nav bar with diving image

Tags: html, css

I'm really struggling to get this navigation-menu with a image that splits the navigation to work. Responsive is a big plus. I don not believe the current code is on the the right way to go, so please be open minded of how to approach this problem.

HTML

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul class="nav-left">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="nav-logo"></div>
    <ul class="nav-right">
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#nav {
    width: 400px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav-left, .nav-right, .nav-logo {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
.nav-left {
    background: red;
}
.nav-right {
    background: red;
}
.nav-right, .nav-left {
    width: 100px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 0;
}
.nav-logo {
    background: yellow;
    width: 30px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
ul {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: justify;
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[image: Mockup]

**Update 05.05.14**
Updated it with my current code as requested.

Comment: ... what have you tried? Post code and a fiddle for better results.

Comment: Showing your current HTML and CSS would be useful.

Comment: This should be doable with layered `<div>`s where the image is a `background-image:` tag

Comment: I don't think it's wise to post code, as I'm sure my current solution(s) are way off:(

Comment: @LcLk: I don't think that is the best solution. I belive in a solution where the image acutally splits the to navigation-parts, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Andreas, in which case wouldn't two links, followed by the image followed by two links work? I don't think we can find your idea of a best practice solution without knowing what you are currently doing

Comment: @LcLk: Understand. So this is my current solution: http://jsfiddle.net/HHQCe/ Cannot find a way to justify the nav-elements. And I'm not a fan of how I split it with  nav-left, nav-right. Makes it hard to turn it into a responsive solution. Do you have any ideas to get me on the right track?

Comment: @Andreas, the sleekest solution would be using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), is using a framework out of the question?

Comment: @LcLk: No, I'm not using frameworks. I want to undestand html/css properly, hence this post.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone ahead and made a slightly responsive header for you: [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcLk/56BJe/1/) (Note: random coffeeshop logo borrowed from google image search... man I should go get a coffee)

The idea is to use the `html5` `nav` element to contain your links, each with a `width:20%` so it resizes with the width of the screen.
The image is positioned with `background:url('...') no=repeat center;`  to avoid sizing problems. It's in a separate div to allow you to stripe the `<nav>` element. This is possible with [pure css](http://lea.verou.me/2010/12/checkered-stripes-other-background-patterns-with-css3-gradients/).

As you want to position the links vertically they are nested in divs, and space for the image is made using an empty div with the same `width:20%;` property as the link containers.

The design breaks once you get close to small mobile device widths (as the links cover the image). For this you can use [@media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/).

I hope this gives you a starting point, but design is very subjective and there are many different ways to do it.
It may be worth while to style your page with [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and inspect their CSS to see what's happening.

Answer (score -2):

Can you please add your css and html codes into your qustion then I can help you with a best solution. Also if you want then email me your codes, I will send you the best solution.

Orherwise just add a class `.navfix` on the main navigation container `div` or `ul`. then add the style property `z-index:9999999` for the class `.navfix` into your stylesheet. Also if you have use any other div for the background then   you have to add same thing for the nav background container but here `z-index` property should be negative or lower then other one.

**sample** :

```
.navfix {
  z-index:9999999;
}
```

for background container (if you have)
then

```
.navfix {
  z-index:9999999;
}
.backgrounContainerClassName {
 z-index:-1; 
}
```

Comment: @Andreas The original post was simply: *"Can you please add your css and html codes into your qustion then I can help you. Also if you want then email me your codes, I will send you the solution."*